# Removing space at the end of string

Tags: trim

I would want to remove white spaces at the end of the string. I used below code but it doesn't work, also it does not throw any error.

`df[ABC_Col].str.strip()`

`ABC_Col` is the column header

Could you please help me on this?

Thank you

Comment: Please tag the language you’re using

Comment: Is this supposed to be tagged `javascript`? Can you confirm what language this is, `python` or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `strip` to the data frame column on the left hand side:

```
df[ABC_Col] = df[ABC_Col].str.strip()
```